# Edit SQL Query in SSAS Tabular Model

Tags: ssas, ssas-tabular

I have created a local instance of a Tabular model using Visual Studio's SSAS Project Template.

Still a little new to this, but I have used an OLEDB connection to import data using a SQL Query.

The table is imported successfully, but I want to make changes to the Query I used to import the data.

Below circled in blue is my connection, and circled in red is the table properties option.

[image]

When I select the table properties, I don't see the query. I just see the connection string;

[image]

The same goes for the Power Query Editor

[image]

Where do I find the Query I made to edit it? I cannot find it anywhere!

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I am not familiar with SSAS, but the interface looks very similar to PowerBI.

Currently you have imported a whole table, you cannot apply an SQL query to that connection.

To import the results of a SQL query you need to create a [native query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/tabular-models/ssas-import-query?view=asallproducts-allversions).

For example, if I want to query a Postgres database that would look like this:

```
let
    Source = Value.NativeQuery(PostgreSQL.Database("db.host.path", "db_name"), "select * from some_table where condition = 1")
in
    Source
```

I understand that you don't have a Postgres database, so the command would look something like this (not sure, can't test):

```
let
    Source = Value.NativeQuery(#"OleDb/provider-SQLNCLI11 1", "select * from some_table where condition = 1")
in
    Source
```

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party here, but adding to what @saaru Lindestøkke said, this is how this is described in the documentation:

> Create a data source connection If you don't already have a connection
> to your data source, you need to create one.
>
> In Visual Studio > Tabular Model Explorer, right-click Data Sources,
> and then click New Data Source. In Get Data, select your datasource
> type, and then click Connect. Follow any additional steps required to
> connect to your data source. Enter a query as a named expression In
> Tabular Model Explorer, right-click Expressions > Edit Expressions. In
> Query Editor, click Query > New Query > Blank Query In the formula
> bar, type
>
> Value.NativeQuery(#"DATA SOURCE NAME", "SELECT * FROM ...") To create a table, in Queries, right-click the query, and then select
> Create New Table. The new table will have the same name as the query.

See [Import data by using a native query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/tabular-models/ssas-import-query?view=asallproducts-allversions)